# MINIX: Retrieve a file's inode by the filename

Tags: linux-kernel, system-calls, stat, minix

In **MINIX 3.2.1**, I want to create a new **system call** which will be given a filename as a parameter and will print the certain file's inode number.

I have created and modified all the needed files to do that.

So in order to retrieve the inode of the file by its name I want to use the default system call:

```
int stat(char *name, struct stat *buffer)
```

http://minix1.woodhull.com/manpages/man2/stat.2.html

in the body of my new system call handler which is

`int mycall_1(void);` inside `/usr/src/servers/vfs/misc.c`

But when I compile and try to test the new system call, at the point where the `stat` system call should be invoked, it actually won't and instead it's printing the message:

`sys_call: ipc mask denied SENDREC from 1 to 1`

So, is is forbidden to use `stat` inside my new system call?
And if so, is there any other way to retrieve the inode of a file by the filename?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

*stat* is a system call which contains many core functions. You can not use a system call from within a system function because of the very structure of Minix that requires messages exchange between the client and server processes so as to implement the system call itself.

The corresponding system function is [do_stat](https://www.cise.ufl.edu/~cop4600/cgi-bin/lxr/http/source.cgi/fs/stadir.c#L113) and also can not be used to your purpose.

Ultimately, all the file handling functions that you need in Virtual File Server trace back to **lookup** and **advance**.

Shall we examine the [path.c](http://cinnabar.sosdg.org/~qiyong/qxr/minix3/source/minix/servers/vfs/path.c) file in VFS directory, we eventually find *lookup_init* and *eat_path* to be the most appropriate functions.
In the example below the first initializes/prepares the node details to the *lookup* struct, while the later depends on *advance* and resolves the given path to the node.

```
int do_printinode() {
struct lookup resolve;
struct vnode *vp;
struct vmnt *vmp;
lookup_init(&resolve, m_in.m3_ca1, PATH_NOFLAGS, &vmp, 
&vp);
resolve.l_vmnt_lock = VMNT_READ;
resolve.l_vnode_lock = VNODE_READ;
vp = eat_path(&resolve, fp);
if(*vp!=NULL) printf(“inode: %d\n”, vp->v_inode_nr);
else printf(“inode: -\n”);
return 0;
}
```

Ofcourse other files will have to be created or modified as well to implement a proper system call.